# Python SQLite 3 скрипт заполнения столбца из другой таблицы

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

Всем добрый вечер.
Прошу прощения , если вопрос глупый, но я новичок и не могу кое что понять.
Использую Python и Sqlite3
У меня есть две таблицы в БД.
Первая называется employees, а вторая registered_em.
В первой таблице есть столбец id_reg(он является внешним ключом на вторую таблицу ) во второй таблице этот столбец является первичным ключом. Мне необходимо из второй таблицы перенести эти значения для моих сотрудников в первую.
То есть:
В первой есть сотрудник Kira
Во второй таблице она тоже есть , там у неё есть reg_id как мне для неё перенести этот reg_id в первую таблицу ?
Надеюсь понятно.
Ниже прикладываю скриншоты таблиц БД
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUHfh.jpg![введите](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUHfh.jpg!%5B%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5) сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcEOy.jpg)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Такое решение мне бы подошло? 
Только сейчас пришло на ум.

Comment: update employees
set e.reg_id = r.reg_id
from employees e
    inner join registered_emp r on
        e.username= r.username_reg

Comment: Решил сам, отбой